# FreeBSD: connect to switch console

Tags: terminal, console, freebsd, emulation

I am using FreeBSD to connect to a juniper switch using console connection.

I have crossover network cable: 1 end in switch and other in my freebsd laptop.

What do I need in freebsd and how do I watch what is going on when I poweron the switch?

Answer (score 1):

A console connection has to physically be made using a console cable to the device using either a special ethernet or serial cable. See if you can do a virtual console connection over ssh or telnet.

Comment: I am using ethernet cable. But how do I detect it on my FreeBSD machine? Thanks.

Comment: What protocol on top of the ethernet does the Juniper switch console app run on?

Answer (score 1):

This point has not been made clearly enough yet: Serious Networking Equipment often has an RJ-45 console port that is **not ethernet at all**. You need a cable or adapter with RJ-45 on one end and DB-25 or 9 on the other end. (and on a PC with no serial ports you probably need a USB serial adapter too.)

Here's an example of documentation for a console cable: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB13272&actp=RSS

There are many variants, so you have to get specific with the model number to find out for sure what you need.

Comment: I have SRX 210 switch. Which has ethernet like console port. I am using cross-over Ethernet cable. Should I not use that? do I need that rj45 to db9 adapter? and attach that to my laptops serial port?

Comment: @hari I just googled "juniper srx210 console" and the first hit I got clearly shows a serial console: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/task/configuration/services-gateway-srx210-connecting-to-cli.html and they say the adapter is provided in the "accessory box"

Comment: Okay, and, can I connect it directly to a monitor screen?

Comment: That question froze by brain. I don't know how to proceed. Have you never seen a serial port before?